# Data not being populated with dataframe - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

This code :

```
schema = StructType([StructField('p', StringType(), False),StructField('h', StringType(), False)
                   ,StructField('q', IntegerType(), False),StructField('r', IntegerType(), False)])
rdd = sc.parallelize(['str' , 'str' , 1 , 1])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).show()
```

returns error :

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'str' in type <class 'str'>
```

Have I not defined the schema correctly? The ordering is string,string,int,int so why cannot initialize with `rdd = sc.parallelize(['str' , 'str' , 1 , 1])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the rdd with a list of lists where each sublist is a row:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([['str' , 'str' , 1 , 1]])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  p|  h|  q|  r|
+---+---+---+---+
|str|str|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```